# Encrypted in IPHONE using Cocoa AES Rijndael and NEED to decrypt using .NET

Tags: iphone, cocoa, aes, encryption

I try this code [aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone](http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/2009/02/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/)

But it always fail with Padding Exception

Iphone
Decrypted Text: nvlWOYHbCvYjHHWjGVaLePLkyzT/wM//YMS6nRwqp/l7w89a1QNTPaifmV78wCXcaTv4tqY9wLuIKjyvtdCjx9lU1lNTEJQgF/CToHAE+G0=

Password: cbvde432Y12rqdazxs

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use PaddingMode.PKCS7 on the .Net side and kCCOptionPKCS7Padding on the iPhone side? That should sync them up.

Comment: Yes, on .Net, we use PKCS7 padding. But on the Iphone, it just uses the default option. But i am not sure about the Cocoa AES's default Padding and Cipher mode